# How to use tf.data.Dataset.apply() for reshaping the dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am working with time series models in tensorflow. My dataset contains physics signals. I need to divide this signals into windows as give this sliced windows as input to my model.

Here is how I am reading the data and slicing it:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
def _ds_slicer(data):
    win_len = 768
    return {"mix":(tf.stack(tf.split(data["mix"],win_len))),
            "pure":(tf.stack(tf.split(data["pure"],win_len)))}
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({
    "mix" : np.random.uniform(0,1,[1000,24576]),
    "pure" : np.random.uniform(0,1,[1000,24576])
})
dataset = dataset.map(_ds_slicer)
print dataset.output_shapes
# {'mix': TensorShape([Dimension(768), Dimension(32)]), 'pure': TensorShape([Dimension(768), Dimension(32)])}
```

I want to reshape this dataset to `# {'mix': TensorShape([Dimension(32)]), 'pure': TensorShape([Dimension(32))}`

Equivalent transformation in numpy would be something like following:

```py
signal  = np.random.uniform(0,1,[1000,24576])
sliced_sig = np.stack(np.split(signal,768,axis=1),axis=1)
print sliced_sig.shape #(1000, 768, 32)
sliced_sig=sliced_sig.reshape(-1, sliced_sig.shape[-1])
print sliced_sig.shape #(768000, 32)
```

I thought of using [tf.contrib.data.group_by_window](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.5/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/group_by_window) as an input to dataset.apply() but couldn't figure out exactly how to use it. Is there a way I can use any custom transformation to reshape the dataset?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're just looking for the transformation [`tf.contrib.data.unbatch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/unbatch). This does exactly what you want:

```py
x = np.zeros((1000, 768, 32))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)
print(dataset.output_shapes)  # (768, 32)
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.unbatch())
print(dataset.output_shapes)  # (32,)
```

From the documentation:

> If elements of the dataset are shaped [B, a0, a1, ...], where B may vary from element to element, then for each element in the dataset, the unbatched dataset will contain B consecutive elements of shape [a0, a1, ...].

---

### Edit for TF 2.0

*(Thanks @DavidParks)*

From TF 2.0, you can use directly [`tf.data.Dataset.unbatch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#unbatch):

```py
x = np.zeros((1000, 768, 32))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)
print(dataset.output_shapes)  # (768, 32)
dataset = dataset.unbatch()
print(dataset.output_shapes)  # (32,)
```

Comment: In TF 2.0 this is moved out of contrib to the dataset object `tf.data.Dataset.unbatch()` so just `dataset = dataset.unbatch()` from 2.0 onward.

Comment: Thanks ! I added this in the answer.

Comment: This simple change from a `yield from` to unbatching in my custom generator dataset reduced data generation time from >10h to 6 minutes. Kudos!

Comment: Thanks for the bounty and congrats for your data pipeline :)